# why we need standardization and normalization in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

Data standardization and normalization, so what is the difference between this terms ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](https://medium.com/@rrfd/standardize-or-normalize-examples-in-python-e3f174b65dfc) is a good example based explanation about normalization and standardization which I just mention some points of it here:

> **Normalization :**
>
> 1. Normalization makes training less sensitive to the scale of features, so we can better solve for coefficients.
> 2. Normalizing will ensure that a convergence problem does not have a massive variance, making optimization feasible
>
> **standardization :**
>
> 1. *(reason of using Standadization)* Compare features that have different units or scales.
> 2. Standardizing tends to make the training process well behaved because the numerical condition of the optimization problems is
>      improved.

Comment: The link is not working!!